# Search and Replace with JS: RegExp that does not include html code

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm looking for a regexp that matches to strings in html body but does not influence strings that appear in title tags e.g. I have:

```
words = new Array("Android","iOS");
change = new Array ("http://www.google.com","http://www.apple.com");
obj = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]; 
// search and replace
for (i in words) {
    re = new RegExp("\\b("+words[i]+")\\b", "ig");
    str = obj.innerHTML.replace(re,'<a href="'+change[i]+'">$1</a>');
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = str;
}
  }
```

So I have a list with words an the JS is replacing these words (eg replacing `iOS' by <a href='http://www.apple.com'>iOS</a>`) from HTML Body. But: it also replaces HTML Code like '`<title = 'iOS'> ->` this becomes `<title='a href='http://www.apple.com'>iOS</a>'` . How can the regexp can be changed that `<title='...>` and stuff are not changed

Adam

Comment: please post your code

Comment: now try to edit your question and post the code there

Comment: Don't use RegExp to parse the DOM.

Comment: Fortunately, there's no such HTML as `<title='iOS'>`, so this will never happen.

Comment: You know what I mean... eg <img src="..." alt="iOS" title="iOS"> -> both 'iOS' are replaced and this changed the whole code...

Comment: So you mean a title _attribute_, not a title _tag_. But then I don't understand what this has to do with titles. You have the problem everywhere you have the text iOS' that shouldn't be translated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a look-ahead to ensure the target is not within a tag (ie the next angle bracket is a `<`):

```
re = new RegExp("\\b(" + words[i] + ")\\b(?=[^>]*<)", "ig");
```